# Select from MySQL (dates)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a DB table with a column named `date`

I want the user to select a date from a input field (Post), convert the date to d/m/y and then select that date from the DB.

I have the below code, which doesnt seem to be working

```
if(isset($_GET['chosen_date'])) {
$chosen_date=$_GET["chosen_date"];
$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($chosen_date));

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time_sheets where user_id=$user AND     date=$newDate")or die('Error Line 202' . mysql_error());
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is `$user` set? Is `chosen_date` set? Any errors being outputted; is reporting on?

Comment: What does `$newDate` return...?

Comment: `$newDate` is a string, so it should be quoted - `date='$newDate'`. Also, why are you using `d/m/Y` and not using MySQL's date column type `Y-m-d`. It will be easier to work with your dates in the future in this format

Comment: @Sean - Thanks didnt spot that! :)

Comment: Don't use `d/m/y` format.  Always use `yyyy-mm-dd` for date constants.

Comment: Does the query return anything? I think it should be `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time_sheets where user_id=".$user." AND date=".$newDate)` or something simillar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mysql's standard Y-m-d format, and the date is a string and should have quotes around it. $user is not defined but you probably just omitted that code

$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($chosen_date));

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time_sheets where user_id={$user} AND     date='{$newDate}'")or die('Error Line 202' . mysql_error());

Comment: Oh, even better than `'Error Line 202'. mysql_error()`, there is this: `'Error line '.__LINE__.' of file '. __FILE__ ." mysql_error: ".mysql_error()`